# Script to sort and filter in shell

Tags: shell, awk, scripting

I want to do a `ping` to `10.20.88.33 - 1 = 10.20.88.32` (gateway IP). How can i write a script to do from below output ?, should sort and ignore same AS (autonomous number) from 3rd column to get Neighbor state IP.

In the below output neighbor state IPs `10.20.88.19` & `10.20.88.20` contains same AS number, so the gateway is `10.20.88.33 - 1` (gateway is always -1 IP from last prefix of neighbor state IP).

Help to me to create a script to do this ?

```
186590d10b29:~ prabhapr$ cat 1.txt 
Neighbor        V           AS MsgRcvd MsgSent   TblVer  InQ OutQ Up/Down  State/PfxRcd
10.20.88.19     4        65006   68570   68090     2638    0    0 3d04h         429
10.20.88.20     4        65006   68579   68091     2638    0    0 3d04h         429
10.20.88.33     4        64800    9128    8999     2638    0    0 10:13:41      418
```

Comment: a good question has both sample input and expected output... `Help to me to create a script to do this` no, SO is not about that.. you ask when you tried some code and got stuck

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Input: 186590d10b29:~ prabhapr$ cat 1.txt 
Neighbor        V           AS MsgRcvd MsgSent   TblVer  InQ OutQ Up/Down  State/PfxRcd
10.20.88.19     4        65006   68570   68090     2638    0    0 3d04h         429
10.20.88.20     4        65006   68579   68091     2638    0    0 3d04h         429
10.20.88.33     4        64800    9128    8999     2638    0    0 10:13:41      418

Comment: Output should be

10.20.88.32 (rules are, this filtered out from the list of different AS number (64800) Neighbor IP 10.20.88.33 minus 1 at the last octet.

Comment: Any idea to write a script, I can cut and filter column wise but raw wise how can we do it ?

Comment: awk provides the possibility to store data into array variables. You may do some arithmetic calculations in the actions (and even in the predicates). The syntax is similar to C. There are special predicates `BEGIN` and `END` which are performed before 1st line and after last line. Google these topics or read an awk manual and try to put it together. If you get stuck then edit your question and show what you've got so far. This will improve the chances for help...